# Install specific version of NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I need to install this NGINX Ingress Controller Git release https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.22.0 in my Kubernetes cluster. Can anyone share the steps on how to do it?

I did some research, but could not find any useful article.

**Additional information**

- I'm managing the cluster using helm. So is there a way to set it up using helm?
- Is any other approach recommended?

Comment: how are you managing your cluster? helm or something else?

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm managing it with helm.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to install nginx-ingress controller using(manage using) helm, you can use the link for the same, below command.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

If you want to install a particular version of ingress controller you can export the values into your local and change the tag and then run helm install above using the customised values file as shown below.
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_show_values/

```
helm show values [CHART] [flags] > values.change.yaml

helm install chart -f values.change.yaml -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can display all available helm chart versions using:

```bash
helm search repo ingress-nginx --versions
```

```bash
NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 4.2.1           1.3.0       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 4.2.0           1.3.0       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 4.1.4           1.2.1       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx 4.1.3           1.2.1       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
....
```

Then, choose the version you want `CHART VERSION`, here 4.2.0

```bash
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --version 4.2.0
```